# Redirect user from ajax routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

For instance, I have generated by `resources :companies` routes:

```
/company/123/
/company/edit/123
/company/new
```

All these routes are used for Ajax functionality.

And now if user opens it **directly in browser**, he/she will see all raw JSON data.

How to redirect these requests like theese to the site root (http://site.com/)?

I think, we can use `x-requested-with` HTTP header to detect ajax/direct requests, but I don't know how to deal with it in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  before_filter :check_ajax

  def check_ajax
    if (request.env['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] !~ /XMLHttpRequest/i)
      redirect_to '/nahuy/' # your url
    end
  end
```

Redirects all non-Ajax requests `'/nahuy/'` :)